# Create variables from POST

Tags: php, post

I've got an old script here, which's based on the functionality that it creates variables from the POST Array. I know it's old and shouldn't be used, but which parameter do I need to activate it? `$_POST['output']` should automatically become `$output`.

I've been searching on php.net and google, but I can't seem to find the name of this parameter.

Comment: Why this shouln't be used? A security issue?

Comment: @xy_ Assume you rely on a var called $is_authorized which is set to 1 after login procedure in order to allow access to further information. Someone who knows this, can attach a ?is_authorized=1 to the url in order to gain access.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Easy

```
extract($_POST);
```

Now

```
echo $output;
```

EDITS :

The above method has been deprected now. It can be achieved like this

```
extract(array_intersect_key($_POST, $array_of_expected_keys))
```

Comment: Is there also a parameter which does this automatically?

Comment: You can loop through to do it

Comment: No I mean, I tought there was a parameter in the php.ini which would do this automatically, without the export function.

Comment: You're talking about `register_globals`, which has been deprecated for security reasons.  Speaking of which, you should not do `extract($_POST)`; you should do `extract(array_intersect_key($_POST, $array_of_expected_keys))` instead.

Answer (score 0):

There was in previous versions of PHP.
From [PHP Post variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7247572/php-post-variables)

`register_globals` was an old way of getting the submitted values with their name as variable rather than as post ,get, and request variables. But this is deprecated in newer version. You need to your code for this to accept `$_POST['email']` instead of `$email`.